# mysql2 in rails3 'table exits already' how to delete that?

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-12.04

I delete the project robin_offine for some reason and when I restart it and run

rake db:create,it claims:

```
robin_offline_development already exists  
robin_offline_test already exists
```

ignore that and add migration named events

if rake db:migrate

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'events' already exists(cuz i have done that last time)
```

The problem is ,I couldn't find where the table is

```
SHOW DATABASES;  
+--------------------+  
| Database           |  
+--------------------+  
| information_schema |    
| test               |  
+--------------------+   
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Even don't know which one to delete

sorry I'm new to mysql
the system is Ubuntu 12.04LTS

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: robin_offline_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: robin_offline_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: robin_offline_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

and my migration file is just what run

```
rails g model events
```

nothing special

develop.log

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  [1m[36m (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` [0m
Migrating to CreateEvents (20121213091145)
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
Mysql2::Error: Table 'events' already exists: CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  [1m[36m (1.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` [0m
Migrating to CreateEvents (20121213091145)
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
Mysql2::Error: Table 'events' already exists: CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  [1m[36m (1.9ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` [0m
Migrating to CreateEvents (20121213091145)
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
Mysql2::Error: Table 'events' already exists: CREATE TABLE `events` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Database != table, you might want to do `SHOW TABLES FROM test`.

Comment: I see ... It's in the information_schema;  but how could I delete that?I try  DROP DATABASE information_schema;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

Comment: In `information_schema` ? Can we see your `config/database.yml` and possibly, your migrations ?

Comment: i mistake that , but the `test` database is empty

Comment: `information_schema` is the database containing information about the users, the databases, the tables, ... You don't want to touch it. From what `SHOW DATABASES` shows, the databases don't exist. Are you talking to the same server and with the same user ?

Comment: yes.show you my log...but i don't have a schema now

Comment: what's more,I could see it in `rails c`,but the migration remains undone...it means, which I do last time does effects me now...

Comment: I guess for some reason, your table `schema_migrations` was not up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I just run

```
rake db:drop
```

and do the migration again, all goes well again

and `rails db` to goto the database and do whatever you want.